# English equivalent of *refrán*, which is less formal than a proverb

Tags: single-word-requests, spanish

Spanish makes a subtle distinction between *proverbio* [proverb] and *refrán* [?].  This distinction was described well [here](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17128/9385).  I'll attempt to translate informally from that answer.

> Although the two words can be considered synonymous, the connotations
>   are different:
>
> - *refrán*: a colloquial, folksy saying or piece of advice.  It needn't be about something weighty.  It often features a rhyme, making
>     it catchy and easy to remember.
> - *proverbio*: a bit more serioius than *refrán*.  Generally speaking, it doesn't provide advice about banal matters, but has more of a
>     moral, ethics tone.
>
> For example:
>
> > *Marzo ventoso y abril lluvioso sacan a mayo florido y hermoso.* [Loosely: April showers bring May flowers; literally: Windy March and
> >     rainy April bring out a flowering and beautiful May.]
>
> The subject matter of this *refrán* is the weather.
>
> A proverb, on the other hand, is more formal, has a more serious subject matter and attempts to teach something.

Here's an example of a proverb:

> *No es oro todo lo que reluce.* | All that glitters is not gold.

My German spouse informs me that *refrán* seems to be similar to **Bauernregel** (guidance for farmers), but with a particular focus on the weather.  For example

> *Der April macht was er will.* | April does whatever it wants to.

My question is **what is the closest equivalent to *refrán* in English**?

---

**Edit after question was closed as a duplicate of a question that was closed because a sample sentence wasn't provided**:

**Sample sentence**:

> Spanish has a charming *refrán* that's relevant to your situation: [....]

An additional thought: I'd like ideally to find something as graceful as, for example, "turn of speech."  But that won't work because a *turn of speech* is a fragment, not necessarily a whole sentence.

Comment: Google `proverb synonym` and then weed through the suggestions to find one you like.

Comment: Your weather example is literally (and literarily?) an *idiom*.

Comment: @HotLicks - In the original language the difference was too subtle for most dictionaries to make a distinction.  I can rattle off plenty of words that a thesaurus would list, but I'm not sure which (if any) would match up with *refrán*.  In conversation, there are situations where I recast the sentence and talk about "the old song and dance."  Because "refrán" also refers to something that gets over-used (*el mismo refrán*).  Hmm.  Maybe *homily* approaches it?

Comment: @jxh - I disagree.  First off, an idiom need not be a whole sentence, and I think *refran* is.  Second, an idiom means more than the sum of its parts.  In other words, if you consider the literal meaning of each word of an idiom, and add them all up, you get something rather different from the actual meaning of the idiom.

Comment: Well, it sounds like your question is really for the Spanish SE.

Comment: @HotLicks - Questions that look for the English equivalent of something used in another language are on topic here.  On the other hand, a question about subtle differences in meaning of English words would not be on topic at any of the beta language sites.

Comment: @aparente001: I was only commenting on the specific "April showers bring May flowers." example, which is definitely an idiom.

Comment: @jxh - I still don't think so.  You can understand that sentence just fine by figuring it out word for word, literally.

Comment: @aparente001: Perhaps the literal meaning, but the figurative meaning of *bad things now, good things later* may not be clear to someone until the metaphor is explained.

Comment: "April flowers bring May flowers" is considered a [proverb](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/April_showers_bring_May_flowers) (actually, it looks like [English and Spanish versions are related too](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/do-april-showers-bring-may-flowers/)).

Comment: @Laurel: Even better.

Comment: @jxh - Interesting.  You're saying that metaphor = idiom?

Comment: @Laurel - Note I said that was a *loose* translation.  I took the gestalt of the Spanish phrase and inserted a similar phrase that is well known in English.  I followed this with a literal translation (word for word), and I indicated that the second one was *literal*.

Comment: @aparente001 Actually, I was referring to the literal translation, which I found to be very similar to an [older version of the expression we have in English](https://books.google.com/books?id=DfgNAAAAQAAJ&pg=RA1-PA7) (because it also mentions a windy March).

Comment: @laurel - I looked at your link, thank you.  Here's their version: "March winds and April showers bring forth May flowers." Yes, very close to *windy March and rainy April bring out a flowering and beautiful May.*

Comment: *popular saying, proverb, saying, adage, byword, wise saying, by-word* http://www.wordmagicsoft.com/dictionary/es-en/refr%E1n.php My choice: **popular saying**.

Comment: @aparente001: I don't think all metaphors are idioms. I think an expression is an idiom if it is commonly and colloquially used where its literal interpretation does not exactly match the situation at hand.

Comment: @jxh - I like your explanation of *idiom* a lot.  // I don't consider the flowers example in my question to be an idiom.  But let's just agree to disagree on that since it's a bit tangential to my question.

Comment: "old chestnut", "cliche", "saying"

Comment: @aparente001: FWIW: https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11408/87426

Comment: By the power of my gold hammer.... anyway, I dislike closing questions with closed questions.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Thanks.  But I'd still like to get a *rule* about this.

Answer (score 42):

I think you just want to use ***saying*** (which is used in your definition of *refrán*):

> A *saying* is a sentence that people often say and that gives advice or information about human life and experience.
>   *We also realize the truth of that old **saying**: Charity begins at home.*
>   <sub>[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/saying)</sub>

In a list of words related to *proverbs*, ***saying*** is defined as:

> A short well-known expression — a pithy remark of wisdom and truth or a general advice.
>   *Example: The road to hell is paved with good intentions.*
>   <sub>[Smart Words](http://www.smart-words.org/quotes-sayings/aphorism-proverb-idiom-saying-pun.html)</sub>

Comment: Thanks. I feel unsure.  I think *dicho* lines up well with *saying*.  Let me ask you this.  Which is a broader term?  Proverb or saying?

Comment: *Saying* is definitely broader. There is no single term I can think of for *informal advice in the form of a pithy sentence* other than *saying*. I can think of other terms like *old wives' tale* or *piece of advice* (again in your definition).

Comment: That's helpful.  I'm getting closer.  Proposal: *informal saying*.  To distinguish from *proverb*.

Comment: @aparente001 I'd say "informal saying" is possibly redundant.  The term "saying" is typically inferred to be informal (to me).

Comment: I like "saying," it's pretty folksy. Close second would be "maxim" - which carries the feel of a slogan and also often has a rhyme (early to bed, early to rise, makes a man healthy, wealthy and wise). Here are a bunch of collected maxims, which might be useful to you: http://libraries.udmercy.edu/find/special_collections/digital/cfa/index.php?field=keyword&term=Maxim

Answer (score 27):

If you don't like ***saying*** (which is jxh@'s excellent suggestion), how about an ***adage***:

> a saying often in metaphorical form that typically embodies a common observation. Example: *She reminded him of the adage: "A penny saved is a penny earned."*
>
> <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adage)</sub>

Or possibly an ***aphorism***:

> 1 : a concise statement of a principle
>
> 2 : a terse formulation of a truth or sentiment : adage. Example: *the high-minded aphorism, "Let us value the quality of life, not the quantity"*
>
> 3 : an ingeniously terse style of expression : aphoristic language
>
> <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aphorism)</sub>

I think ***adage*** is probably closer to the weather examples.

Comment: *Aphorism* seems to be more formal, not less: between *aphorism* and *proverb*, seems like *aphorism* would be the *proverbio*. *Adage* is a much-superior suggestion, I think.

Comment: @KRyan I agree - I've reordered.

Answer (score 24):

Perhaps mildly obscure in today's language but I'm astonished that nobody has mentioned the word ***refrain*** yet. It has two meanings, but it's the noun we're interested in, which appears primarily in musical terminology:

> *<sup>2</sup>refrain*
>
> /rɪˈfreɪn/
>
> 1.
>   a regularly recurring melody, such as the chorus of a song
>
> **2.
>   a much repeated saying or idea**
>
> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/refrain)

This corroborates with the given suggestion of **saying** above. With cursory research it is difficult to find a citable source for the Spanish, but it appears that *refrain*'s etymological root is the same as the given *refrán*:

> *<sup>2</sup>refrain*
>
> Middle English refreyn, from Middle French refrain, alteration of Old French refrait melody, response, from past participle of refraindre to break up, moderate, from Vulgar Latin *refrangere, alteration of Latin refringere
>
> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/refrain)

> *refrán*
>
> Borrowed from French refrain, from Latin *re-* (“back, again”) + *frangō* (“break”).
>
> [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/refr%C3%A1n)

[*frangō*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/frango#Latin) being a conjugation of [*frangere*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/frangere#Latin), whose derived terms include [*refringo*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/refringo#Latin), which is itself etymologically composed of '*re-*' and '*frangō*' and is a conjugation of the Latin [*refringere*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/refringere#Latin) which was mentioned by *Merriam-Webster* regarding the origin of the English '*refrain*', above.

This is why I think 'refrain' may actually be the closest equivalent word, even if it isn't particularly widely used outside of musical terminology.

Comment: TIL *refrain* has a second definition. Which is cool and all, but doesn’t speak well of trying to use it in this fashion, in my opinion.

Comment: @KRyan I've actually seen 'refrain' used in this manner before, both in writing and spoken.  I feel like I've even seen the word used in a sentence exactly as you gave in the above comment.  Native US English speaker fwiw.

Comment: @NinjaDuckie - I'm glad of your answer and comments about usage but when discussing contributions and opinions about contributions, regarding my question, I'd appreciate it if everyone would keep a respectful tone toward everyone else.  Maybe "good lord, no" is considered gentle and neutral where you live, but for me it comes over a bit strong.

Comment: @aparente001 Uh... nothing here struck me as disrespectful, and his response was good: I *have* heard the phrase “that old refrain” and similar. Without *old*, though, I didn’t recognize it; I actually thought of “old refrain” as a [set phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_phrase) in which *refrain* (in the musical sense) was being used metaphorically.

Comment: @aparente001 (It may be worth noting that “Good lord, no!” is, itself, a set phrase in English to agree heartily with someone’s critique by way of saying that you never meant to imply otherwise. A particularly devout adherent of the Ten Commandments might find it disrespectful, since it violates the Third Commandment, but in American society at least that level of devotion is unusual and the phrase is not particularly noteworthy for most of the population.)

Comment: @aparente001 I apologise if my comment sounded strongly-worded; as you correctly assert and as KRyan states as well, it was actually just a hearty agreement. I can see how it may have been misinterpreted, however. No harm done, I hope.

Comment: @KRyan All's well that ends well...

Comment: @NinjaDuckie - ... I'm deleting obsolete comments.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to 'saying' you could use 'saw':

> **saw**: a sententious saying; maxim; proverb

Usually combined with 'old':

> He could muster an old saw for every occasion.
>
> [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/saw)

Comment: I see the connection, but sadly it's not a charming word.  Generally speaking, a *refrán* is charming and gracefully devised. (I was going to say *written* but it didn't feel right, since I think *refranes* were generally part of an oral tradition.

Comment: @aparente001 I think it's a good match but I see your point.  It's also a little archaic.  Many people are not familiar with the term.

Answer (score 3):

**Platitude** is a possible one that occured to me.

> Platitude
>
> /ˈplatɪtjuːd/
>
> Noun
>
> A remark or statement, especially one with a moral content, that has been used too often to be interesting or thoughtful.
>
> [google.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Aplatitude)

Answer (score 2):

Consider the word **Adage:**

> a saying often in metaphorical form that typically embodies a common observation
>
> - She reminded him of the adage: "A penny saved is a penny earned."

[Definition from the Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adage).

Answer (score 2):

The question is based on a false premise: that a subtle difference in connotation in one language means that other languages make the same subtle difference in connotation. To flip the direction of translation, there is a subtle difference in English between *safety* and *security*, but the closest Spanish equivalent of *safety* (*seguridad*) is also the closest Spanish equivalent of *security*.

The English word *proverb* does not have the prestige connotations of *proverbio*. For example, [Britannica says](https://www.britannica.com/art/proverb)

> Proverbs sometimes embody superstitions (“Marry in May, repent alway”), weather lore (“Rain before seven, fine before eleven”), or medical advice (“Early to bed, early to rise,/ Makes a man healthy, wealthy, and wise”).

If you want to make a distinction within the same sentence (e.g. to translate *Acaban de publicar un libro de proverbios y refranes españoles*), the most straightforward translation would be *...proverbs and sayings...*; but otherwise the appropriate English word is *proverb*.

Comment: Not built on a premise, but yes, built on a hope. // Are you saying the set of *proverbios* and *refranes* = the set of *proverbs*?

Comment: @aparente001, no, I'm saying that the set of *proverbios y refranes* is a subset of the set of *proverbs*. I don't wish to commit to whether or not it is a proper subset.

Comment: Okay, there may be some as yet unidentified critters out there that are also part of the set of *proverbs*. // I guess the wikipedia quote below the Spanish Beta question I linked to would lend support to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered a **colloquialism**?

> **Colloquialism**
>
> \ kə-ˈlō-kwē-ə-ˌli-zəm \
>
> <sup>1</sup> a : a colloquial expression "Chicken out" is a colloquialism for "to lose one's nerve."
>
> b : a local or regional dialect expression "Bodacious" originated as a Southern colloquialism.
>
> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/colloquialism)

Comment: *Refrán* is more of a set phrase than that, and also it's always a complete sentence -- but thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest "refrain," since it can also mean "a comment or complaint that is often repeated." It's slightly formal, but it's probably the closest literal translation of "refrán," based on what you've said- and it shares a root, too, so that's a bonus.

Comment: It's already been suggested by [@NinjaDuckie](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/444432/44619)